# Cannot install ati/amd graphics through wubi on MacBook Pro

Tags: 12.04, ati, dual-boot, wubi, macbook

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 through Wubi on my Windows dual boot on a late 2011 MacBook Pro. Everything seems to be in working order, except when I try to install the ATI/AMD graphics drivers; it fails and directs me to view `/var/log/jockey.log`.

How do I fix this?